# Why can't I change the color of the status bar?

Tags: react-native, expo, statusbar

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StatusBar,Platform,Text,StyleSheet,View} from 'react-native';

export default class TabsScrollableExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar 
        barStyle = "light-content" 
        hidden = {false}
        style={styles.color} // I've also tried this way backgroundColor="white"
        translucent = {true}
        networkActivityIndicatorVisible = {true}
        />
 </View>
      
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
  container :{
  backgroundColor:"white", 
  },
  color:{
    backgroundColor:"white"
  }
   
  });
```

**All other properties work correctly but the background color does not change.**

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this.

```
<StatusBar 
    barStyle = "light-content" 
    hidden = {false}
    backgroundColor="white"
    translucent = {true}
    networkActivityIndicatorVisible = {true}
    />
```

Comment: I've also tried this way as I specified before and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#backgroundcolor) the right way is backgroundColor="white". Maybe there is another problem. On which device are you testing? try without translucent (I know it should work anyway, but maybe there is a bug there with your android version). Try with rgb colors (#ff0000). Let me know your results.

Comment: I've also tried this way as I specified before and it doesn't work.